# JQuery Datatables pass all selected checkbox values from all pages

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to cannibalize the answer to this question from several others on SO but no luck.  I have a paginated table, and the option for the user to select all rows across all pages.  I'm trying to pass the selected checkbox values to my controller but I can't figure out how to get the value of the checkbox.

What I have so far:

```
var usersGrid = $('#usersGrid').dataTable();
var userIds = [];

userIds = usersGrid.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/User/SelectUsers/",
    data: { lockIds: userIds },
    dataType: "json",
```

My controller is just expecting an array of values but the array contains the name of the checkbox and the value, which it does not like.  I know that part of this is supposed to be the next step:

```
userIds.push({ 'name': 'extra_param', 'value': 'extra_value' });
```

but I can't find it adequately explained.  Think I'm close here, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So this works:

```
    var usersGrid = $('#usersGrid').dataTable();

    var selectedUsers = [];
    var userIds = [];

    selectedUsers = usersGrid.$('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();

    $(selectedUsers).each(function (i, field) {
        userIds.push(field.value);
    });
```

but it strikes me as kind of hacky to create the two arrays.  Still wondering if there's a way to just retrieve the value from selectedValues and not the name of the checkbox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `.find()` method? It sounds like your problem is targeting dynamically created elements.

```
userIds = usersGrid.find('input[type="checkbox"]').serializeArray();
```

Comment: That didn't work, same result.  In the controller the array of values are all passed in as 00000-0000-0000-0000 (we're using guids)

Comment: Two things could be happening... dataTable() is probably run asynchronously and maybe it's not being created before userIds is being called. The other thing is dataTable() maybe isn't creating the table inside the `#usersGrid` container. I would use Chrome/Firefox tools to figure out what the actual id or class of the table container is, and use `setTimeout` (just for testing) to see if your userIds are getting created before your data table.